# Why do I have a negative profit?

Tags: trading

I am testing a demo account for trade Eur/USD  GBP/USD.
But whatever action I take : Buy , sell . I am always with a negative profit..

How?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What sequence of actions are you trying to take? Why do you expect that you would make a profit?

Comment: I think that he was expecting p&l to be 0 rather than -1.2 EUR or a profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bid offer spread will always have a lower price for you to sell to the market than you buy at and so you will start off with a negative profit based on that spread.

Example:
Fiber (EUR/USD) bid 1.09**79**3 ask 1.09**80**5 spread 1.2 @ 15:50
Expressed in bps you will pay 80.5 when you buy at this time and can sell at 79.3 so will make a loss off 1.2 bps per unit if you sell immediately.
This is effectively a loss of 0.00012 euros per euro multiplied by your leverage factor (mine is 10,000 for fiber) to give a 1.2 EUR loss per unit.